# Display driver stopped responding and was recovered

Tags: memory, drivers, windows-10, display-driver, vram

Yes, that famous popup...

I tried a lot of things, nothing helped.
In the end I figured out that it was a problem with my vram, for some reason if it goes above 2gb vram it stops responding(Prob when it starts using the normal ram)
My declocking my card -500 it can run games for a longer period of time but sill crashes the driver.

Is there a some kind of way to limit the vram usage?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem with the cable, using HDMI cable instead of VGA cable seemed to fix the problem. VGA cable is not fast enough for 1080p screen and in the end it would lose connection. vram had nothing todo with it